# sec:authorize in js append html as string not work

Tags: javascript, java, html, ajax, spring-thymeleaf

I'm new to JS HTML JQuery ajax and I currently have an issue with my HTML case. To describe the most exactly what I'm facing right now first I'll talk about the process. The project is about SpringMVC + Thymeleaf & Thymeleaf Security5 + Spring Security.

- The time the user logs in, the user with role USER won't see the  tag by `sec:acthorize`, which works fine at first

The origin code work fine first when the user with role USER load into the page ( mean not show the  tag for the user with role USER):

```
<tbody id="tableBody">
   <tr>
      <td>
         <a sec:authorize="hasAuthority('ADMIN')" href="#" th:attr="onclick='showConfirmationPopup(\'' + ${user.userName} + '\');'" class="delete" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip"></a>
      </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

- But then after I sort the table of content which call Ajax JQuery for recreate the view like this :

```
function populateTable(data) {
   $("#tableBody").empty();
   var row = $("<tr>");
   var actionColumn = $("<td>");
   actionColumn.append("<a sec:authorize=\"hasAuthority('ADMIN')\" href='/api/update/" + user.userName + "' class='settings' title='Update' data-toggle='tooltip'></a>");
   row.append(actionColumn);
   $("#tableBody").append(row);
}
```

And the result is it still shows the  tag although the current authentication user has the role USER.

The code which calls the function above is:

```
   $.ajax({
      url: "/rest/api/pagination-by-search",
      type: "GET",
      data: formData,
      success: function(data) {
         populateTable(data);
      }
   });
   function populateTable(data) {
      $("#tableBody").empty();
      var row = $("<tr>");
      var actionColumn = $("<td>");
      actionColumn.append("<a sec:authorize=\"hasAuthority('ADMIN')\" href='/api/update/" + user.userName + "' class='settings' title='Update' data-toggle='tooltip'></a>");
      row.append(actionColumn);
      $("#tableBody").append(row);
   }
```

I tried to log the user's role, and it logs the role USER as expected. However, the view still shows for the user with role USER.
The version I used:

- SpringBoot version: 2.7.14
- thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5
- java-version: 1.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you already have a Thymeleaf object called user in your code. To conditionally show the link based on the role attribute of this object and also authorize it using Spring Security, you can use both `th:if` and `sec:authorize` attributes together.

Here's how you can modify the code:

```
actionColumn.append("<a th:if=\"${user.role == 'ADMIN'}\" sec:authorize=\"hasAuthority('ADMIN')\" href='/api/update/'" + ${user.userName} + " class='settings' title='Update' data-toggle='tooltip'></a>");
```

This code will only render the link if the user object's role attribute is set to `'ADMIN'`, and it will also check if the currently authenticated user has the authority `'ADMIN'` using Spring Security's `sec:authorize`. This should help you control the visibility of the link based on distinct roles.

Comment: Thanks but this way seems to work temporarily.

Comment: Yah but at least it work.